# How can I sum an array with while loop? [Python]

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, while-loop

So I tried to sum the array with a while loop, something is going wrong. I get this type of error:

total = total + index[numbers]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Here's my code

```
numbers = [1,5,6,3,7,7,8]
index = 0
total = 0
while index <= len(numbers):
    total = total + index[numbers]
    index += 1
```

The answer that I should get is 37, with **using** the while loop.

Comment: It's `numbers[index]`.

Comment: oh I see thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change <= to < and index[numbers] to numbers[index]

```
numbers = [1,5,6,3,7,7,8]
index = 0
total = 0
while index < len(numbers):
    total = total + numbers[index]
    index += 1

print(total)
```

Try this code.

Use < instead of <= and numbers[index] instead of index[numbers]

**You can do this using sum() function.**

```
numbers = [1,5,6,3,7,7,8]
total = sum(numbers)
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Change `index[numbers]`  to `numbers[index]`

Answer (score 1):

The answer Ailrk provides is correct, I just want to add that in Python you can just use `sum(numbers)` to find the sum of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
numbers = [1,5,6,3,7,7,8]
total = 0
while numbers:
    total = total + numbers.pop()
print(total)
```

While we have a number in numbers, pop it our and add to total. The while loop will break when all numbers are popped as an empty list is False in Python